# TV show pilot with red-haired, cat-eyed alien girl

Tags: story-identification

I watched the pilot for a series I thought I would like but now I can't find it, I can't remember what it was called.

It had a young woman with bright red hair(I think) and her eyes were like a cats. She was traveling with a human man who treated her like a daughter but he had 'adopted' her. I remember they went to a settlement and there were different types of aliens there.

At the settlement, the son of the rulers fell for a girl of a different breed.

Comment: Since you're a new user, if the answer below is correct, please mark it as such by clicking the gray check mark to the left of the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: See OP acceptance comment above. Duplicate target has formally accepted answer.

Comment: @Otis - Someone seems to have foolishly deleted the acceptance comment.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate.  There's almost no overlap in the details about the show.

Answer (score 10):

Red-haired alien girl with cats eyes strikes me as being a good match for "[Defiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defiance_(TV_series))"

Per wikipedia:

> The story begins in the year 2046. Earth has been radically
>   transformed, causing changes in topography, the extinction of plant
>   and animal species, and the emergence of new species. The series
>   follows Joshua Nolan (Grant Bowler) and his adopted Irathient daughter
>   Irisa (Stephanie Leonidas), who have put down roots in Defiance, a
>   city-state community where humans and several extraterrestrial races,
>   collectively known as Votans, coexist over the partially re-built
>   ruins of St. Louis.

[image]

Comment: Not to mention the reference to the inter-species relationship between Alak Tarr and Christie McCawley.